# Populate Backbone collection with json encoded php array

Tags: javascript, php, json, backbone.js

I am trying a simple test. To populate a Backbone collection from a json encoded php array.

```
var MyObjectModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse:function(response){
        return JSON.parse(response);
    }
});

var MyObjectView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<a id="<%= id %>" href="#"><%= name %></a>    '),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes)); 
        return this;
    }
});

var MyList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'testRest.php',
    model: MyObjectModel
});

var MyListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$("#app"),
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.on('add',this.addOne,this);
        this.collection.on('reset',this.addAll,this);
    },
    addOne: function(objectModel){
        var objectView = new MyObjectView({model: objectModel});
        this.$el.append(objectView.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function(){
        this.$el.empty();
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne,this);
    },
    render: function(){
        return this;
    }
});

var myList = new MyList();
var myListView = new MyListView({collection:myList});

myList.fetch().done(function(){
    myListView.render();
});
```

The HTML page is as basic as possible

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone-min.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test2.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

it works fine when the file testRest.php contains

```
echo json_encode("{\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"one\",\"color\":\"ff6600\",\"phoneNumber\":\"+123456789\"}");
```

but as soon as I try to have more that one item in the returned object:

```
echo json_encode("[{\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"one\",\"color\":\"ff6600\",\"phoneNumber\":\"+123456789\"},{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"two\",\"color\":\"800080\",\"phoneNumber\":\"\"}]");
```

I have an error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined

Does anyone encountered the same issue ? Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do `return JSON.parse(response)` - the response has already been parsed. The parse method is so that you can return nested data for the Collection to convert into models e.g. `return response.data` is typical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your Backbone code but you are doing two things wrong with the php script:

1) Set the Content-type header to json
2) `json_encode` takes a php array

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$resp = array(
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'one',
        'color' => 'ff6600',
        'phoneNumber' => '+123456789'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'two',
        'color' => '80080',
        'phoneNumber' => ''
    )
);

echo json_encode($resp);
```

Also as I said in the comment you don't need to do `JSON.parse` jQuery already parses to an object as long as the `Content-type` header is set. The default Backbone method for parse already returns the response object so you don't need that override at all (unless you were getting at nested data).